# Unable to run vue application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I created a project using below command,

```
npm init vue@latest
```

The project was created like,

[vue project setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkiXS.png)

After that run below command,

```
npm install
```

then run the below command,

```
npm run dev
```

But I got the below error,

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwtbH.png)

Package.json File,

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFIOn.png)

I tried all the way like cleared cache but couldn't helped me. Also reinstalled the node but didn't worked. Also given full permission to the folder.

npm version  - 8.7.0
node version - v16.14.2

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Same problem when I using node version 14.15.0, but I switch node to version 16.13.0 this problem did not show up. I delete the 'node_modules/.vite' folder and switch node back to version 14.15.0, this problem show up again.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the `.vite` folder ? This is a problem with vite rather than vue.

Comment: After deleting package-lock.json and node_modules and reinstall the packages with npm i, now I have vite: 2.7.12 working properly, although it still shows a bunch of Failed to load source map... at the first time of running npm run dev

Comment: Yes I tried all the way, but still I'm getting same issue

Comment: Finally downgraded vite version to 2.8.6. then it is working properly. Only have an issue from vite version 2.9.0 and above